# Is there a way to represent the 4th kinematic equation of velocity squared visually?

Tags: physics, kinematics

Kinematic Equations:

\begin{align}
v &= v_0+at \\
\Delta x &= \left( \frac {v+v_0} 2 \right) t \\
\Delta x &= v_0t + \frac12 at^2 \\
v^2 &= v_0^2 + 2a\Delta x
\end{align}

So for the fourth equation, final velocity squared is found without $t$, time.

My question: is it possible for this equation to be derived or explained visually/graphically?

For the first three equations it is easy to come up with a visual representation as to why the equations make sense under constant acceleration. I tried to imagine the 4th equation as a $v^2$-vs.-$t$ graph, that is quadratic. But my mind can’t understand how $$2a\Delta x$$ can be explained.

I understand how the equation is derived algebraically, but my question is whether the equation can be easily explained in geometric terms like the other kinematic formulas.

Answer (score 1):

One way that you could visualise this is by using the graph $a$ vs $\Delta x$. Since $a\Delta x$ has the same units as $v^2$ this means that the area under an acceleration vs displacement graph from $0$ to $\Delta x$ has to be equal to the area under the graph velocity vs velocity from $v_0$ to $v$.
[image]
In kinematics the acceleration is constant so the area under the $a$ vs $\Delta x$ graph is simply $a\Delta x$ meanwhile the area under the velocity graph would be the area of the trapezium of side lengths $v_0$ and $v$ and height $v-v_0$.

$$a\Delta x=(v-v_0)({v+v_0\over2})$$
$$a\Delta x={v^2-v_0^2\over2}$$
$$v^2={v_0}^2+2a\Delta x$$
or more properly:
$$\int_0^{\Delta x}adx=\int_{v_0}^vvdv$$
$$a(\Delta x-0)={v^2\over2}-{{v_0}^2\over2}$$
$$v^2={v_0}^2+2a\Delta x$$
Hope this is what you were looking for.